# No power to interior lights, etc

Tags: electrical, mercedes-benz

I got Mercedes A Class W168. Recently I got a weird problem, when I switch the key, only battery & SRS lamps lit at  dashboard. Engine, headlamps, radio, horn, windows, power steering work. Wipers, signal lamps, interior & dash lamps, central locking are out of service, even when engine running.

Ceiling lamp turns on for a second then goes immediately.

What would be the problem? It doesn't seem like blown fuse problem to me.

Comment: since battery and srs lamps are working so it probably wire is lose somewhere and it just sparks enough to light the ceiling lamp i think you should go to the mechanic

Comment: Which key are you "switching" to? or am I understanding what you wrote incorrectly? "when I switch the key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the vehicle off *and* key out of the ignition locate the `fuse box` and remove `fuse #30 (DAS transponder/RFL/Instrument cluster)`. Give it about 5-10 second before reinstalling it and then put the key in the ignition and see if everything works. It's possible that the `DAS module` had gotten a little confused at some point and had placed itself into a limp"-type mode. Pulling the fuse and then reinstalling it will kill the modules power and force a hard reset.

**NOTE**: If this fixes your issue and for some reason it happens again down the line, Then make sure to have it checked by a shop with MBZ equipment (Star Diagnostics).`

Comment: Yes that's what I did today, fuse #30 a 7.5A got a contact problem, I unplugged & re-plugged it and viola... Actually I did check all the fuses one by one while flashes on...

Comment: Glad you got it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

> It doesn't seem like blown fuse problem to me.

Are you sure about fuses? Did you check all with a multimeter / ohmmeter?

Comment: questions should be left as comments not answers.

Comment: No, I didn't think that multiple fuses can die at once... Dimmed ceiling lamp lits when turned on then goes off when lits at max. Need to read it's logs...